# select ID by its parent id

Tags: javascript, html, parent

I have 2 elements with the same id , and I need to access one of them so I though I could access by its node parent. Is that possible? If not what can I do?

Comment: Don't have two elements with same ID. Period. It's wrong, it's bad and it's invalid.

Comment: Two elements cannot have the same ID, it's not valid HTML.

Comment: id stands for 'identifier'. So, it has to be unique. It won't give error. You can use it but, it will generate conflict while accessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's note valid code to have the same id in a html document. Use `class` instead `id`.

Read more to understand the role of each one: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Id should be unique in one html page.

Answer (score 0):

Never have elements with same IDs. Use classes instead. All modern browsers are solid in terms they assume element ids are unique.

Answer (score 0):

In a single page/form, ID field has to be unique throughout. Otherwise solution/project will not build.

Answer (score 0):

Best way, Have two different unique id and access whichever you want with `getElementById();`